# I cannot print the variable with my text

Tags: python, string, variables, printing

I'm trying just to create a simple line of code but I can not seem to figure out how to print a string and a variable at the same time. If someone could plz help me that would be great.

```
day = 1

print ("Day Number: ("+day+")")
```

Comment: try: `print("Day Number: {}".format(day))`

Comment: Check out more info on formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thanks! that solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Three ways:

```
print("Day Number: {}".format(day))

print("Day Number: %d" %day)

print("Day Number:", day)
# Note: if using python 2, this last one needs to be without parentheses, 
# or the parentheses will show up in your output too. 
# But this is the least flexible way anyways.
```

All result in `Day Number: 1`. Personally, I Prefer the `.format()` way, and there are lots of options you can use with it. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information. For more information on the use of the `%` formatter, see the section [Old String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations), but also note that they say it is **obsolete**, and they recommend the `.format()` method.

Comment: New and improved [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings): `f'Day Number: {day}'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your variable to a string in order to add it to other strings

```
day = 1
print("Day Number: (" + str(day) + ")")
```

Comment: No need to explicitly cast to string, just use `format` or `%`
-1

Comment: I noticed your solution, this is mine. It works. Is it the best solution, no it is not.

Comment: Why post it if it isn't the best solution? To concatenate with + is a bad habit, especially when there's much better options.

Comment: I gave a possible solution to the OP. Others are more than welcome to offer their answers, the OP can then select which is best suited for him. Your -1 is just a testament to the toxicity of some of the users. If you have an answer, provide it. In the context of this code the ideal solution would be `print("Day Number: (1)")`. What's the purpose of initializing and storing a value in memory in this context?

Comment: Sorry, I know you have the best of intentions but it's still a bad answer teaching bad habits. You don't have to search hard why that is: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```
day = 1

print ("Day Number: ("+str(day)+")") 

print ("Day Number: ( %s ) " % day )
```

The top one explicitly casts the day into a string. The second one uses the `%` operator to put the data into the string. In Python, `int` cannot be cast to `str` implicitly.